# Examples of a modern ARIMA algorithm from scratch?

Tags: r, time-series, python, arima, algorithms

Where can I find a modern/robust algorithm for the fitting of an ARIMA model? Or in other words, if one were to implement an ARIMA model from scratch in 2021 what would be the most correct/efficient algorithm?

I have been looking into a number of different ARIMA implementations.

1. C: [ctsa](https://github.com/rafat/ctsa/blob/master/src/boxjenkins.c)
2. Julia: [ARIMA.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/TimeModels.jl/blob/master/src/ARIMA.jl)
3. Python: [statsmodels.tsa.arima.model](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/arima/model.html#ARIMA)
4. R: [arima.c](https://gist.github.com/naufraghi/911292)

All of these sources differ a good deal in lines of code from 36 in Julia to 1660 in ctsa. Also, of these scripts listed above none of their implementations are the same.

It seems that there are statespace implementations, but I remember reading that not all statespace models are arima and not all arima are statespace. If this is true I would want to avoid a statespace implementation. AS154[1] seems like one of the first algos, but it looks like it is fitting an ARMA and it is using Kalman filtering. If my understanding is current, I think we are estimating ARIMA with maximum likelihood. Are their any recent papers or old papers that are considered the gold standard which lay out the ARIMA fitting algorithm?

[1]: Gardner, G, Harvey, A. C. and Phillips, G. D. A. (1980). Algorithm AS 154: An algorithm for exact maximum likelihood estimation of autoregressive-moving average models by means of Kalman filtering. Applied Statistics, 29, 311--322. 10.2307/2346910.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for `auto.arima()` in the [`forecast` package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/), or the more recent `ARIMA()` in the follow-up package [`fable`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fable). This is not the most recent implementation (the relevant paper is [Hyndman & Khandakar, 2008](https://www.jstatsoft.org/htaccess.php?volume=27&type=i&issue=03&paper=true)), but:

1. It has been the workhorse for academic and practical forecasting for the last decade. Any bugs or systematic weaknesses must have been purged by now. [Searching for `auto.arima` on CV currently yields 1245 hits.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=auto.arima)
2. There is still some development going on, most recently a change to the algorithm for setting the seasonal differencing order.
3. The lead author is [Rob Hyndman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman), who is pretty much the guru of forecasting. Seriously, I know of very few people whose implementation of an ARIMA algorithm I would trust more than Rob's. Look at his contributions here, and note that he spent many years as the chief editor of the *International Journal of Forecasting*. When Rob speaks, forecasters listen. If he found a better way to fit an ARIMA model, it would be in his packages before the rest of us would even know about it.

Comment: Thanks. I just had a look at the fable implimentation. It looks like it still calls stats::arima() on line 221. https://github.com/tidyverts/fable/blob/master/R/arima.R#L221

So you are saying that R's arima.c with fables auto.arima built on top of it is the gold standard. And I agree. I think that Rob Hyndman's work is great. I just find it interesting that we are still calling the same arima.c script.

Comment: Hi: AFAIK, every ARIMA model does have a state space representation with the condition that it is not unique unless more conditions are imposed. I can't find the paper at the moment but you may want to take a look at this paper if you can get it. ( otherwise, just request it from authors ).  It converts the ARIMA model to state space and then estimates it. I remember it being one of the clearest explanations as far as conversion of ARIMA to state space.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222547290_The_ARMA_model_in_state_space_form

Comment: @Alex, see the comment by mlofton.